# How to create a count up timer in a text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below I have a javascript count down timer which works fine:

```
    <h1><span id='countdown'><?php echo $dbSessionDuration; ?></span></h1>

...

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var time = <?php echo json_encode($dbSessionDuration); ?>,
      parts = time.split(':'),
      hours = +parts[0],
      minutes = +parts[1],
      seconds = +parts[2],
      span = $('#countdown');


    function correctNum(num) {
      return (num<10)? ("0"+num):num;
    }

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        seconds--;
        if(seconds == -1) {
            seconds = 59;
            minutes--;

            if(minutes == -1) {
                minutes = 59;
                hours--;

                if(hours==-1) {
                  alert("timer finished");
                  clearInterval(timer);
                  return;
                }
            }
        }
        span.text(correctNum(hours) + ":" + correctNum(minutes) + ":" + correctNum(seconds));
    }, 1000);

});
```

Now what I thought of doing is use the example above and manipulate it to now do the opposite and create a count up timer starting with 00:00:00 (hours, mins, secs).

But issue is that it is not working. Nothing is happening. I don't know if I need an hours in the function below because as its a countup, the hours could go up to as many hours as it wants. But my question is how can the count up timer be fixed so that it is fully working?

```
<p><input type='text' class='responseTime' name='responsetime' value='00:00:00' /></p>

...

$(document).ready(function() {
var response = "00:00:00",
      parts = time.split(':'),
      hours = +parts[0],
      minutes = +parts[1],
      seconds = +parts[2],
      input = $('.responseTime');


    function correctResponse(responsenum) {
      return (responsenum<10)? ("0"+responsenum):responsenum;
    }

    var responsetimer = setInterval(function(){
        seconds--;
        if(seconds == +59) {
            seconds = 00;
            minutes--;

            if(minutes == +59) {
                minutes = 00;
                hours--;

                  return;

            }
        }
        input.text(correctResponse(hours) + ":" + correctResponse(minutes) + ":" + correctResponse(seconds));
    }, 1000);


  });
```

**UPDATE:**

Also as a side note I realised that the countdown timer I believe is counting down every 2 second for every second. How can this be sorted for the count down timer and included in the count up timer?

The code below I have changed to include increment ++ and to include .val rather than .text but what is happening is that it starts with 00:00:00 and then it just drops down to 00:59:60 and then just stops:

```
var response = "00:00:00",
          parts = time.split(':'),
          hours = +parts[0],
          minutes = +parts[1],
          seconds = +parts[2],
          input = $('.responseTime');


        function correctResponse(responsenum) {
          return (responsenum<10)? ("0"+responsenum):responsenum;
        }

        var responsetimer = setInterval(function(){
            seconds++;
            if(seconds == +59) {
                seconds = 00;
                minutes++;

                if(minutes == +59) {
                    minutes = 00;
                    hours++;

                      return;

                }
            }
            input.val(correctResponse(hours) + ":" + correctResponse(minutes) + ":" + correctResponse(seconds));
        }, 1000);


      });
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but it looks like your decrementing seconds, yet checking for it to be a positive number.  Maybe you should try _incrementing_ ?

Comment: @Rake36 Please look at update

Comment: @user1914374: Please don't keep changing your question / updating it as you get new answers.

Comment: @Oerd It is only to show what current code looks like so you know what is happening. Shall I just remove it?

Comment: No, it's ok, just don't change it so that this question becomes another one ;)

Comment: Use `time = "00:00:00"` on the first line of your updated code. Works for me.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? Use a single variable to track time and then extract the data as you need it. I have provided an answer with more simplicity than the code you are currently using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily modify the current countdown timer like here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergiu/CDpeJ/3

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    seconds++;
    if(seconds == 60) {
        seconds = 00;
        minutes++;

        if(minutes == 60) {
            minutes = 00;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    var newTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if(!newTime.match(/^(20|21|22|23|[01]\d|\d)(([:.][0-5]\d){1,2})$/)) newTime = "finished";
    $('#timeInput').val(newTime);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: The hous can go up past 24, e.g. can go up to 32 hours if it wants to. DO I just need to change that if statement for hours just to include return and thats it?

Comment: I want it in a text input rather than a span. How can I get it working in text input because timer not working in text input with your code (made slight changes to from span to text input when trying to implement it)

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, use the `val('value')` function to change/set the value of an input field.

Change `input.text(...)` to `input.val(...)`

Also:

1. After incrementing seconds use `seconds = seconds % 60;` to bring them back to `0`.
2. Also, consider using `data-attributes` for passing values to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would have implemented such a timer:

```
function startTimer() {
    var time = 0
    setInterval(function(){
        time++
        var sec = time % 60
        var min = (time-sec)/60 % 60
        var hour = (time-sec-min*60)/3600
        var str= hour+':'+("0"+min).slice(-2)+':'+("0"+sec).slice(-2)
        $('.responseTime').val(str)
    },1000);
}
```

With an input with class `responseTime` to display the timer. (Why not use id btw?)

Start whenever appropriate calling `startTimer()` (in your example using `document.onload=startTimer`)

If you want to start from another time than 0, set `time` to the appropriate number of seconds.
For a countdown, replace `time++` with `time--` (probably adding some logistics for `time==0`)

Comment: For other people this will be very useful. I have already ogt an answer for my timer but if people want to create their own timer, yours is a very good solution +1

Comment: Fair enough. The other answers are closer to your code, so they probably answer your question better. I do however think simplicity is key when writing code (as at some point someone (you?) might have to read and see what is going on).

Comment: I like this answer more because if I want to, lets say make a serverTime clock which resets on midnight, only thing i'd have to do is to make a check at first `if (time == 86399) time = 0; And for the ones that don't know, `.slice(-number)` is the best solution there is for zero-padding because it works for any number of digits you set.

Answer (score 0):

Count up try this

```
var millis = <?php echo $dbSessionDurationTime; ?> ( diff in seconds )

function displaytimer(){
    var hours = Math.floor(millis / 36e5),
        mins = Math.floor((millis % 36e5) / 6e4),
        secs = Math.floor((millis % 6e4) / 1000);
        //Here, the DOM that the timer will appear using jQuery
        $('.count').html(hours+':'+mins+':'+secs);  
}

setInterval(function(){
    millis += 1000;
    displaytimer();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added Mariusnn solution and Oerd suggestion to JSFiddle with changing val to text in Jquery.

HTML file

`<body>
    <h1 style="color:blue">Time</h1>
    <h2><span class="responseTime" style="color:indianred"></span>
    </h2>
    </body>`

JS code

`
    var startTimer;

```
startTimer = function() {
var time;
time = 0;
setInterval((function() {
    var hour, min, sec, str;
    time++;
    sec = time % 60;
    min = (time - sec) / 60 % 60;
    hour = (time - sec - (min * 60)) / 3600;
    count = hour + ':' + ('0' + min).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + sec).slice(-2);
    $('.responseTime').text(count);
    }), 1000);
   };

$( document ).ready(function() {
    startTimer();
});
```

`

#### JS fiddle solution is here.

https://jsfiddle.net/hzLf3e38/4/